# wp.editPost 'API Wordpress' doesn't edit custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, api

When I try to edit custom_fields with wp.editPost. Only edit the other fields, but not custom fields. Custom fields are created again(repeat fields), but will have to be edited.

I am looking: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.editPost

My array with custom fields is:

```
    $content = array(
        'post_id' => (int)$idPostWp,
        'title' => $modificarPostWpDecode['title'], //ok edit
        'description' => $modificarPostWpDecode['content'], //ok edit
        'categories' => $modificarPostWpDecode['category'], //ok edit
        'custom_fields' => array(
            array('key' => 'precio', 'value' => $modificarPostWpDecodeCustom['price']), // no edit, fields will be create again
            array('key' => 'category', 'value' => $modificarPostWpDecodeCustom['category']), // no edit, fields will be create again
            array('key' => 'estrenar', 'value' => $modificarPostWpDecodeCustom['new']), // no edit, fields will be create again
            array('key' => 'currency', 'value' => $modificarPostWpDecodeCustom['currency']), // no edit, fields will be create again
            array('key' => 'search', 'value' => $modificarPostWpDecodeCustom['search']) // no edit, fields will be create again
            )
    );
```

My call to wordpress is:

```
    $params = array(1, WPUSER, WPPASS, (int)$idPostWp, $modificarPostWpDecode);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.editPost', $params, array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'escaping' => 'markup'));
```

Thank a lot!

Comment: What is the reason for you using XML-RPC? Is the php code being run on the same wordpress server? If so, XML-RPC need not be used.

Comment: The code is in another server. I have the same problem with wp.editPost and metablog.editPost.

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#Notes_3), you must pass the custom field's ID to edit the field, rather than the key, which would end up creating a duplicate.

So you need to do two requests, unless you already know the custom field IDs. One request to get all the custom data, loop through the fields, and collect the appropriate IDs to the fields you want to update. The second request will update the fields, specified using the field IDs, not just the key.

The collection of IDs can look similar to the following

```
$custom_fields_to_edit = array(
    'key1' => null,
    'key2' => null
    );

foreach($post->custom_fields as $custom){
    if (array_key_exists($custom->key, $custom_fields_to_edit)){
        $custom_fields_to_edit[$custom->key] = $custom->id;
    }
}
```

where `$post` has been collected using the `wp.getPost` procedure.

You can then proceed as previously, with the following modification to your code.

```
'custom_fields' => array(
    array('id' => $custom_fields_to_edit['key1'], 'key' => 'key1', 'value' => $modificarPostWpDecodeCustom['key1']),
    array('id' => $custom_fields_to_edit['key2'], 'key' => 'key2', 'value' => $modificarPostWpDecodeCustom['key2'])
    )
```

Comment: I know the keys, but doens't work. I tried with wp.editPost and metaWeblog.editPost, but it the same result...Documentation for metaWeblog is: https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_MetaWeblog_API. With id, key, value the result is nothing. Nothing happens.

Comment: @davidcm86 Nothing happens as in, literally nothing changes on the server, or just the custom fields do not change?

Comment: The custom fields dont change with struct id,key,value